# How to change Xcode build setup without modifying project files?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I would like to know if it is possible to change compile settings without modifying the xcode projects.

Example, adding `-Wno-unused-parameter` to `CFLAGS` in such way that it will be used by Xcode when building projects.

This has to work in both case: build made from xcode in GUI or from the console.

If someone asks about why, let's say that the number of projects is quite big and that you may want to alter the options only temporary.

Answer (score 4):

Put the compiler settings you want to change in a configuration settings file. You can create a new one by choosing File > New > New File. The configuration settings file is in the Other group under both iOS and Mac OS X.

To tell an Xcode project to use the configuration settings file, select the project file from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select the project from the left side of the editor. Click the Info button at the top of the editor. You should see a list of build configurations in the editor. Click the disclosure triangle next to a build configuration to have it use a configuration settings file.

Comment: The main idea was to not have to manually edit hundreds of xcode project files :(

Comment: > To tell an Xcode project to use the configuration settings file, select the project file from the project navigator to open the project editor. That's not really crystal clear, can you reformulate please.

Comment: @jokoon In Xcode 4 the project navigator is on the left side of the project window. The project navigator contains a list of files in the project. The project should be at the top of the project navigator. Selecting the project opens the project editor in the project window so you can edit project settings.