# Custom environment variable in XCode 4 - ${CUSTOM_VAR}

Tags: xcode, environment, info-plist

Where to set my custom variable?

I want to use it in info.plist file. For example:

```
Bundle name = ${BUNDLE_NAME}
Bundle identifier = com.mycompany.${BUNDLE_NAME}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add "Configuration Settings File" with keys and values the you want to add/override like:

```
BUNDLE_NAME = custom
```

Then, in the project info pane under configurations you need to pick the configuration to modify and select your newly created configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Here is more detailed instruction how to add configuration settings file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6794287/326017